# Can't get Reddit style working. Nested comments breaking via controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to get a Reddit style comment section working but I'm running into an issue when I attempt to comment on another comment (so a subcomment).

I receive the following error:

> ActionController::UnknownFormat in CommentsController#show .
>   CommentsController#show is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["text/html"] request.variant: [] NOTE! For XHR/Ajax or API requests, this action would normally respond with 204 No Content: an empty white screen. Since you're loading it in a web browser, we assume that you expected to actually render a template, not nothing, so we're showing an error to be extra-clear. If you expect 204 No Content, carry on. That's what you'll get from an XHR or API request. Give it a shot.

Here is my code:

**comment_controller.rb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :find_commentable

  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new comment_params

    if @comment.save
      redirect_to @commentable, notice: 'Your comment was successfully posted!'
    else
      redirect_to :back, notice: "Your comment wasn't posted!"
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
  end

  def find_commentable
    @commentable = Comment.find_by_id(params[:comment_id]) if params[:comment_id]
    @commentable = News.find_by_id(params[:news_id]) if params[:news_id]
  end

 end
```

**comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
 has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
root 'news#index'

resources :news do
 resources :comments do
   resources :comments
 end
end

resources :comments do
 resources :comments
end

end
```

If you would like more information feel free to ask away!

Thank ahead of time.

Comment: Do you have a view template probably at `app/views/comments/show.html.erb` ?

Comment: No i don't l. Let me give that a try.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to work. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have a template to go with your controller action, in this case you need something at:

`app/views/comments/show.html.erb`